Не выводит list[i] в функции
Почему у меня не работает этот код? Выводится только текст "число 5 отсутствует в массиве array":
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]

function search(a, list){

    for(let i = 0; i < list.lenght; i++){

        console.log(list[i])

        if(list[i] == a){
            return true
            break
        }
    } 
    return false 
}

if(search(5, array)){

    console.log("число 5 есть в массиве array")

} else {

    console.log("число 5 отсутствует в массиве array")

}

search(5, array)


потому что length, а не lenght

Ну и IDE'шку себе поставьте какую нибудь, что бы ошибки синтаксиса подсвечивала
